# How to search LinkedList with element from a JList, and print to a JEditorPane

Tags: java, jlist, jeditorpane, listselectionlistener

I need to know how I can retrieve an element in a JList, from which I can use to search a LinkedList and then add that data to a JEditorPane.

I've been trying to use a ListSelectionListener, but have been unable to return the element in the list.

Cheers.

Comment: Show us what you tried.